# Android: Error running app with API from HTTP lib

Tags: android, http, libs

I am making an app that uses the Riot Games API. I enter this line of code to get a response from their website:

```
public int getSummonerLevel() throws JSONException, UnirestException {
    GetRequest gr = Unirest.get("https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/" + region + "/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + summonerName + "?api_key=43f88d5a-a1ad-4a8c-ae5a-9fb2d81e471a");
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> node =  gr.asJson();
    String summonerInfo = node.getBody().toString();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(summonerInfo);
    int summonerLevel = obj.getJSONObject(summonerName).getInt("level");
    return summonerLevel;
}
```

However, I get this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
```

at this line:

```
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> node =  gr.asJson();
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ryanfolz.riotgamesapi"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpasyncclient-cache-4.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.5.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/org.json-20120521.jar')
```

}

Could it possibly be a problem with the dependencies not being compatible wit android? I ran this code in Eclipse and it worked just fine for me.